# Mysql database design for creating quiz with multiple possible answers and textfield for explanation

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

We are creating the database schema for an online quiz. There would be few types of questions asked to each user, for example:

Type 1 question. The question with an answer as yes/no.

Type 2 question. The question with an answer as yes/no. If the user selects yes, then the user has to write few words as to why he says yes.

Type 3 question. The question with an answer as yes/no. If the user selects yes, then the user is given few choices to select. i.e. Is your car accidental? If the user selects yes, then we show check box like engine failed, body repainted, flood damaged, tires damaged etc. The user can select one or more of these choices.

We want to design database for this keeping in mind that it should be flexible to add/delete/update particular type of question in the online quiz and data should be retrieved quickly to check the answer of any given user.

We are considering following DB design:

Table User: Id | Name | Email | Mobile.

Table Question: Id | Type | Title.  (This table contains list of all questions)

Table QuestionChoice: Id | QuestionId | Value. (This table contains value of choices for type 3 questions i.e. engine failed, body repainted etc.)

Table UserResponse: Id | UserId | QuestionId | IsYes | TextForYes

I have few concerns like in table "QuestionChoice", should we keep each value in separate rows or we can save them as comma separated values in single row only?

Is it the best database design OR any alternate?

Comment: NEVER save anything as comma separated

Answer (score 1):

**Users:**

> id | name | Email | Mobile

**Questions:**

> id | title | type

**Options**:

> id | questionId | value

one [questionId] to many [value].

Depending on how much data you have, and if a choice [value] can be used for multiples questions, you could create a table

**Values**

> id | name

and make options as

> id | questionId | valueId

**userAnswers**:

> id | userId |  questionId | choice | optionId | input

Either keep all three in one table, or make one table for each kind of questions.
[or even one table for input, another for choice/option]

Wouldn't you also want a table to "link" your questions? 
[or that part handled with code (?)]

**linkQuestions**: [from and to are questionId, choice is yes/no]

> from | to | optionId | choice

And for your concerns: 
Please try to avoid saving data as comma separated values in a single row.
It is bad practice, for "good" reasons.
[ie: Managing your data will be a pain, sql is relational, and easier to use that way]

Comment: In the case of having only one type of question (multiple choice) with up to 4 answers, is it okay to add the answer values directly to the Questions table? `id | title | answer1 | answer2 | answer3 | answer4`? Could this lead to any negative outcome despite from being limited to 4 answers?

Comment: If you're sure it will be those 4 answers, and that it will not change, why not.
I find it a bit impractical, but that's just a personal preference.